# animateWithDuration doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, uianimation

i want to Fadein/Fadeout animation. so written code like this.

0.0 to 1.0 is fine.
but 1.0 to 0.0 is doesn't work. (set alpha work. but Immediately)

I do not know which code is wrong.

```
if (cellmanager.bMenuShow) // doesn't work
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        [cellmanager.topToolBar setAlpha:0.0f];
        [cellmanager.menuView setAlpha:0.0f];
        [cellmanager.botView setAlpha:0.0f];
        [cellmanager.likeView setAlpha:1.0f];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        NSLog(@"Menu hide");
    }];
}
else
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{ // work
        [cellmanager.topToolBar setAlpha:1.0f];
        [cellmanager.menuView   setAlpha:1.0f];
        [cellmanager.botView    setAlpha:1.0f];
        [cellmanager.likeView   setAlpha:0.0f];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        NSLog(@"Menu show");
    }];
}
```

Comment: For the dosent work block you have `duration = 0.0f`, If you specify a negative value or 0, the changes are made without animating them. refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:)

Comment: @VivekMolkar sorry. i changed 0.5 but same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your are setting the duration of your first animation to `0.0f`. That's why the animation doesn't work. Try a larger value instead.

Comment: sorry. i changed 0.5 but same problem.

Comment: Was `Menu hide` printed out?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the duration is 0, and it means that the animation will be instant, you need to change it to another (positive) value to see animation.

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake here when set duration = 0.0f when hide menu :D